# Looping through a directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm stuck trying to figure out how to print out the images I'm storing in a directory in ASP/C#

I found this, but the problem is it prints out C:\\Visual Studios 2010\Projects\MyTestUploader\Files\img001.jpg

```
string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir);
foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
{
Label1.Text += "<img src=\"" + fileName + "" /><br />";
}
```

For now I just want to simply print out all the images in the directory. I'll worry about formatting them nicely, later :)

Comment: Are you trying to print them out on a printer machine, or display them on the computer screen?

Answer (score 18):

You can use [`Path.GetFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx) to get the file name and extension of the specified path, whilst excluding the directory path (which is presumably what you want).

```
string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir);
foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
{
    Label1.Text += "<img src=\"" + Path.GetFileName(fileName) + "\" /><br />";
}
```

For example, calling

```
Path.GetFileName(@"C:\Visual Studios 2010\Projects\MyTestUploader\Files\img001.jpg")
```

would return `"img001.jpg"`.

Note that you were also missing a `\` to escape the `"` at the end of your attribute value.

Comment: Ah, yea- I typed it quickly from memory as I didn't actually have access to the project when I posted it

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir, "*.jpg");`

Comment: This would still include the path, but restrict the returned string filepath array to just *.jpg files in the specified sourceDir.  The question was how to strip the path from the returned string array of file paths.

Comment: I misunderstood the problem :)

Comment: Notwithstanding, it is a valid point. If the intention is to enumerate image files only, then this amendment should be done too.

Comment: Don’t forget other image types though.